# Megre two maps of dfferent object type into one with completing object value in map1

Tags: java, hashmap

is it possible to merge two maps with the same keys but different object and finnaly get map completed of data from second map?

```
public class Employee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Address address;
}

public class Address {
private String city;
private String country;
private String street;
}


Map<String, Employee> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Address> map2 = new HashMap<>();

//We need map 3 with value in employee completed with address.

Map<String, Employee> map3 = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Employee` class has a setter method for `address` you can do:

```
map1.forEach((key, employee) -> employee.setAddress(map2.get(key)));
```

If you need to instantiate a new `Map`:

```
private Employee setAddress(Map.Entry<String, Employee> entry) {
    Employee employee = entry.getValue();
    return new Employee(employee.getFirstName(), employee.getLastName(), 
            map2.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Map<String, Employee> map3 = map1.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, this::setAddress));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is helpful and resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

if the keys are the same you can easily merge two maps.
If you have the maps in your code like you mentioned the following code should work just fine.

```
map1.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
    Employee employee = map1.get(key);
    employee.address = map2.get(key);
    map3.put(key, employee);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is helpful and resolve my issue.